# Смена фона body при смене слайдов

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jcarousel, slick.js

Привет!
Есть слайдер-карусель, сделанный при помощи плагина slick. 
Потребовалось подкрутить его, чтобы при смене слайда автоматически менялся фон body. Не пойму пока, с какой стороны к этому подойти, подскажите, пожалуйста, может идеи у кого какие есть.

Comment: какой slick вы используйте покажите код?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте callback-функцию `afterChange`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $slider = $(".Modern-Slider").slick({
    //your params here
  });

  //add callback
  $slider.on('afterChange', function(){
    alert('afterChange');
  });

});
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример: https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/egwyXd

Comment: Cпасибо, но у меня почему-то не срабатывает. Я пытаюсь повторить вот это: http://codepen.io/EngCode/pen/PPJQER, только слайдер не на весь экран, а 50% ширины по центру. JS полностью такой же, как по ссылке, но вот хоть убей не работает смена фона, совсем мозг вскипел(

Comment: покажите Ваш сеттинг код

Comment: https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/egwyXd

Comment: Дабы избежать ошибок в codepen в путях лучше не указывать протокол `http`, а писать без протокола `<img src="//path">`, это же правило касается скриптов и ссылок

Comment: @lukas-pierce
Супер, сработало. Сутки спустя появилось еще два обстоятельства: фон должен быть градиентом и каждому из слайдов соответствует определенный цвет фона. Если с градиентом, в принципе, все понятно, то как выстроить код во втором случае? Коллбэк-функция меняет фон лишь при первом переключении.
Еще раз прошу прощения за такие идиотские вопросы, впервые работаю с этим.

Comment: обновил код https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/egwyXd

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен.

```
var backs = ['blue', 'yellow', 'red'];
$slider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, index) {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(/img/back-' + backs[index] +   '.png)');
});
```